# How to configure cURL to use always use a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: curl

I don't want to have to type `curl --socks5 socks5://<proxy name>:<proxy port> <url>` every time I want to make a request to another website. How can I configure cURL to do this by default?

Comment: Why not to create a simple alias, e.g. `alias curlsocks="curl --socks5 socks5://<proxy name>:<proxy port>"`, then just type `curlsocks <url>`? If the proxy name and/or proxy port changes, I'd create a simple bash function or script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I configure cURL to do this by default?

Add the command option to the `curl` [Default config file](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-configfile.html):

> **Config file**
>
> You can easily end up with curl command lines that use a very large
>   number of command-line options, making them rather hard to work with.
>   Sometimes the length of the command line you want to enter even hits
>   the maximum length your command-line system allows. The Microsoft
>   Windows command prompt being an example of something that has a fairly
>   small maximum line length.
>
> To aid such situations, curl offers a feature we call "config file".
>   It basically allows you to write command-line options in a text file
>   instead and then tell curl to read options from that file in addition
>   to the command line.

...

> When curl is invoked, it always (unless -q is used) checks for a
>   default config file and uses it if found. The file name it checks for
>   is `.curlrc` on Unix-like systems and `_curlrc` on Windows.
>
> The default config file is checked for in the following places in this
>   order:
>
> 1. `curl` tries to find the "home directory": It first checks for the `CURL_HOME` and then the `HOME` environment variables. Failing that,
>      it uses `getpwuid()` on Unix-like systems (which returns the home
>      directory given the current user in your system). On Windows, it then
>      checks for the `APPDATA` variable, or as a last resort the
>      `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data`.
> 2. On Windows, if there is no `_curlrc` file in the home directory, it checks for one in the same directory the curl executable is placed. On
>      Unix-like systems, it will simply try to load `.curlrc` from the
>      determined home directory.